# Attempting to migrate to Aptana from Dreamweaver - how to?

Tags: dreamweaver

I have been using Dreamweaver for years, and have used Dreamweaver MX, Dreamweaver MX 2004, Dreamweaver 8 & Dreamweaver CS4. They all carry a common theme and were relatively easy to migrate to each other.

I use, however, very few features of dreamweaver. Specifically:

1. Syntax highlighting
2. Intellisense
3. FTP management/site management
4. The search/replace

The idea I get from Aptana is its much more geared toward the web development/programmer side of things, have better visualizations of classes, etc., and handle everything else just as well. The problem is it is not at all clear to me.

I managed to start a new project, but it didn't associate it with an FTP. So, I created an FTP, and it looks like I can have many FTPs for one project.

My question then is, is there a tutorial or guide to migrating to Aptana from a Dreamweavor's perspective?

Comment: Note: "dreamweavor" is an intentional misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a tutorial for migrating from Dreamweaver, but there is quite an extensive user guide online that details all the tasks and features you will want to use.

Have a look:
http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Main_Page